# Axios call from Node API to PHP server leads to socket hangup

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, axios

I have created an API in Nodejs using Express.

On calling the Node API it reads a file and sends it to a PHP server which is deployed in Apache.The response is received from the PHP server and is sent back to the caller of my Node API.
The **first time when my Node API** is hit it returns the **correct result**.From the **second hit onwards 'Socket Hang up'** is the error that i am getting.

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
const axios = require('axios');
var path = require('path');
const FormData = require('form-data'); 
const form = new FormData();
var fs = require('fs');
var dir = './tmp';

app.get('/file', function(request, responses) {

  new Promise((resolve , reject)=>{
    form.append('file',fs.createReadStream(dir+'/FileCreated.txt'));
    resolve(form);
  }).then(form => {
    console.log('Sending file to the PHP ');
    let url = 'http://121.115.158.12/upload.php';  
    axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url, 
                    // timeout : 3000,
                    data: form,
                    headers: {
                        'content-type': `multipart/form-data;boundary=${form._boundary} `,//
                        }  
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.status);

                    responses.send({status:response.status , data: response.data});
                    responses.end();
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);                  
                    responses.send({status:error.status , data: error.Error});
                    responses.end();
                });               

                request.on('end', function() {
                  console.log('close');
                });

     })

})
```

The error that I receive from second Axios hit onwards.

```
{ Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:323:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:426:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:194:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1103:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config:
   { url: 'http://121.115.158.12/upload.php/',
     method: 'post',
     data:
      FormData {
        _overheadLength: 314,
        _valueLength: 0,
        _valuesToMeasure: [Array],
        writable: false,
        readable: true,
        dataSize: 0,
        maxDataSize: 2097152,
        pauseStreams: true,
        _released: true,
        _streams: [Array],
        _currentStream: null,
        _insideLoop: false,
        _pendingNext: false,
        _boundary: '--------------------------691559357280045881646354',
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 1 },
     headers:
      { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type':
         'multipart/form-data;boundary=--------------------------691559357280045881646354 ',
        'User-Agent': 'axios/0.19.0' },
     transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
     transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
     timeout: 0,
     adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
     xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
     xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
     maxContentLength: -1,
     validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus] },
  request:
   Writable {
     _writableState:
      WritableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        finalCalled: false,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        destroyed: false,
        decodeStrings: true,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: true,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false,
        emitClose: true,
        bufferedRequestCount: 0,
        corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
     writable: true,
     _events:
      [Object: null prototype] {
        response: [Function: handleResponse],
        error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
     _eventsCount: 2,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _options:
      { protocol: 'http:',
        maxRedirects: 21,
        maxBodyLength: 10485760,
        path: '/upload.php/',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: [Object],
        agent: undefined,
        auth: undefined,
        hostname: '121.115.158.12',
        port: null,
        nativeProtocols: [Object],
        pathname: '/upload.php/' },
     _redirectCount: 0,
     _redirects: [],
     _requestBodyLength: 0,
     _requestBodyBuffers: [],
     _onNativeResponse: [Function],
     _currentRequest:
      ClientRequest {
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 6,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Socket],
        connection: [Socket],
        _header: null,
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Agent],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/upload.php/',
        _ended: false,
        res: null,
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        _redirectable: [Circular],
        [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     _currentUrl: 'http://121.115.158.12/upload.php/' },
  response: undefined,
  isAxiosError: true,
  toJSON: [Function] }
```

Observations:

1)The first hit to PHP server(deployed in Apache) is properly logged in the log file of Apache but from the second hit onwards there are no logs in Apache probably telling me that the Axios request is even not reaching Apache?

2)I have built one more Node API just to check if I hit that API then will i get the **socket hangup** error, but this API **runs each time**.Even if I am getting **socket hangup** on the above API, this one runs perfectly.

```
app.get('/random', function(request, responses) {
 console.log(responses);
  responses.send('Just to check');
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still was not able to find the reason for the issue.
I found a roundabout and used shell script to hit the PHP server using **Shell.js** .

This solution worked fine.

Comment: hi... i am facing the same issue.... i have same process to send the data.
node server fetching and sending(post) data using axios to php server which is hosted in apache server.

please suggest me the sample of code

Answer (score 0):

i am facing the same issue.... i have same process to send the data.
node server fetching and sending(post) data using axios to php server which is hosted in apache server.

please suggest me the sample of code

I am using this to post the data

```
const newInstance = axios.create({
        url: `http://something.com/import_data/${channelId}`,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            "USERKEY": "********",
            "PASSWORD": "*******"
        },
        timeout: 1800000,
        httpAgent: new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true })
    });

let result = await newInstance.post(`http://in.truemagic-media.com/import_data/${channelId}`,dataTOSend)
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the same issue as previous posters.

Using axios to post a multipart/form-data request to an API I don't control.

From a node.js script on a Lambda function, first request works fine, subsequent requests do not.

***BUT*** from Postman this is NOT the case, indicating this is a problem with my script not the server.

Also - if my lambda instance running the script is *NEW* instead of simply re-used, the script works fine.

I've tried :

- Explicitly setting content-length header
- Using a new axios https agent instead of the default
- Making the connection-type = 'close' so that we re-create the connection each time rather than re-using the connection.

Nothing seems to make any difference, although clearly Postman is doing something correctly that my script is not.

I can't see anyone who's solved this - tempted to move to another http module (which would be a shame).